# How to check if my variable holds an instance of my class?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Dim myObject As Something
```

There I defined my variable `myObject` of type `Something`.
But, as you can see, I am giving it no value yet.

Sometime on runtime I want to check if `myObject` is holding a value or not. I tried this:

```
If myObject <> Nothing Then
```

But apparently I can't do such comparison. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
If myObject IsNot Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

```
If myObject IsNot Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 If Not IsNothing(myobject) Then 'DoSomething
```